# Angular6 messaging application

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am building angular 6 application, where in few messages would be displayed by default which are coming from API/Services.

However using tinyMCE text editor I can append messages to the existing messages using POST request in API which would do  this.

But I would need to have opinion on how to show default chat messages coming from API and append which got submitted to the existing chat messages.

Any similar idea or any pointer would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unable to understand! Can you please explain

Comment: For example, if you have chat application, and in chat application you have lots of thread with different subject, now if you open any chat with given subject it opens up messages/conversation which had happend for that subject, now I would like to display those messages and append to it whenever user submittes other messages to the existing chat messages. I am usinig tinyMCE editor as default editor to submit new messages. so my query is how I can display existing messages + append newly created messages to the open subject conversation/s.

Comment: Can you show the code of `How you displays existing messages?`

Comment: that is what my query is how to display existing messages + append newly created message. :)

Comment: Well, go step by step: Retrive and show only existing data

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a multistep solution on a high level, based on my understanding of your problem.

I'm assuming that you have gone past the GET and POST initial part and the problem is getting appended data between different browsers.

Server push technologies to the rescue. Depending on the api technologies, there should be something for you to use. For .net web api there is SignalR. Check https://codeburst.io/how-to-notify-your-angular-5-app-using-signalr-5e5aea2030b2 for an example.

If you want something quicker and with no api involvement you could go with long polling techniques. It's the fallback mechanism of web sockets anyway.